# SAS IML append vector to dataset

Tags: sas, sas-iml

**I'm trying to append a new vector to a dataset in SAS IML**

I create these data:

```
proc iml;
x = {1 2 3};
y = {1 2 3};
create data1 var {x y};
append;
close data1;
quit;
```

And then I would like to append new vector "z" to the dataset

```
proc iml;
use data1;
read all;
z = x + y;
create data1 var {x y z};
quit;
```

But this gives me the error "ERROR: The data set WORK.DATA1 is in use, cannot be created"

Comment: Your title says you are trying to append a vector to a matrix, but your example indicates that you want to append a vector to a data set. Which is it?

Comment: Data set, updated the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first close data set data1 before you can do another create of data set data1.

```
proc iml;
use data1;
read all var{x} into x;
read all var{y} into y;
close data1;
z = x + y;
create data1 var {x y z};
append;
quit;
```